# Ejecutar una acción cuando el usuario escribe algo específico

Tags: javascript

Quiero que alguien, cuando escriba algo con una sintaxis determinada se ejecute una acción (por ejemplo, escribo `/time` y se ejecuta un bucle que te da la hora cada segundo).

```js
document.getElementById('escribe').addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    var o = document.getElementById('escribe');
    while(o.value == '/time'){
        // Cuando obtengo la hora, el bucle me peta
        // el nav
    }
});
```

Cuando se ejecuta el bucle, me sale una notificación de consola que lo confirma, pero el nvegador se peta.

Comment: Hola @Vybr. Eliminé tu pregunta sobre los colores en las publicaciones, ya que no está relacionado a programación, pero podrás revisar el [help] o realizar el [tour]. En particular, en [cómo dar formato](/help/formatting) o en [¿qué formato usar para texto largo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1451/127) .. O cualquier otra cuestión acerca del uso del sitio, se puede preguntar en [meta]

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias. Perdóname pues no era consciente del fallo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Por qué estás introduciendo un `while` dentro de un evento?

Lo mejor sería:

> ACTUALIZADO:

**JS:**

```
var interval;
 document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {

       if (this.value == '/time') { //Condición

          interval = setInterval(function() {
               var date = new Date(); //Tomas la fecha
               console.log(date); //Lo pintas en la consola
           }, 1000); //Cada segundo se repite la función
       } else {
             clearInterval(interval); //El intervalo parará de repetirse cuando el valor no sea /time
       }
   });
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="input" type="text">
```

**EDIT:**
Como bien se ha dicho en los comentarios, si pegas el texto directamente en el input no funciona, simplemente porque ese es otro tipo de evento, pero tiene muy fácil arreglo:

**Con jQuery puedes hacerlo así:**

```
var interval;
$("#input").on("input", function() {

      if (this.value == '/time') { //Condición

         interval = setInterval(function() {
              var date = new Date(); //Tomas la fecha
              console.log(date); //Lo pintas en la consola
          }, 1000); //Cada segundo se repite la función
       } else {
             clearInterval(interval); //El intervalo parará de repetirse cuando el valor no sea /time
       }

});
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Ten en cuenta que este código podría no funcionar si copias y pegas el texto con el ratón. Hay usuarios de todos los gustos y colores.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas Pues en ese caso simplemente se podría cambiar el evento usando jQuery, quedando `$("#input).on("input",function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el evento "onchange" para ejecutar una función cada vez que cambie el valor de un objeto "input".

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("myInput").value=""; //vacia el campo.
    if (x=="/time"){
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =date;
      }, 1000);
    } else if (x=="/clear") {
        clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";      
    } else {
      console.log("Orden desconocido " + x);
    }
}
```

```html
Orden:
<input type="text" id="myInput" onchange="myFunction()">
<p id="demo"></p>
```